# Expo run iOS Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I recently upgraded my Expo SDK to version 49. Since making this change, I have discovered that my previous Google Authentication is no longer supported and I am trying to migrate to the recommended `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin`.

The issue with this, is that this library does not work with Expo Go, so I must build my apps for iOS and Android.

I have worked with this library before with no issues on a different app, and running the command `npx expo run:ios` built my app, and allowed me to develop with essentially a native app in real time.

Currently, when I try this command, I get the error:

```
Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '<REST_OF_PATH>/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/AppAuth/AppAuth.h/package.json'
```

I have tried updating my `cocoapods`, ensured all my modules are up to date etc. Removed and reinstalled node_modules, but I cannot get rid of this error. I haven't found anything that I can understand about this.

Any pointers would be great.